# Confusion on Keras Model Return

Tags: python, keras

I have saved and loaded a keras tensor flow classification model.  When training this model, I just paid attention to the accuracy and now what `model.predict` was actually returning.  Now that I'm trying to test deployment of this model, I find confusion around what `model.predict` is actually running.

This is a binary classification problem for image recognition.

The below is the function that takes a base64 encoded picture, decodes it and sends it through to the model:

```
def dapply(input):

    def stringToRGB(base64_string):
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string))
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(imgdata))
        return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    array = stringToRGB(input)

    new_array = cv2.resize(array, (125, 125))
    x = np.array(new_array).reshape(-1, 125, 125, 1)

    pred = model.predict_classes(x)

    return pred
```

I run two instances.  One with each class:

```
#Class 0
dapply(image_n)
```

Returns:

```
array([[1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1]])


#Class 1
dapply(image)
```

Returns

```
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
```

I was expecting 1 number (either `0` or `1`).  Can anyone explain what I'm actually seeing?

Comment: the first element of `input.shape` is the batch size, it seems your are feeding model with an input of shape `(4, 125, 125, 1)`, can you check the shape of `x` in your function?

Comment: It's one image but the shape is as you stated `(4,125,125,1)`

Comment: Seems like converting to grayscale does not remove useles dimensions ank keeps RGBA layers. You should either remove the last dimension (of size 4) of `reshape(1, 125, 125, -1)` (and -1 should always be 4).

Comment: Hi @pLOPeGG. I tride the reshape as you stated and it errors out.  The error was `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_182_input to have shape (125, 125, 1) but got array with shape (125, 125, 4)`

Comment: your model expect a grayscale input but you're passing a 4 channel, your input should be of shape `(batch_size, 125, 125, 1)`. You have to change your preprocessing code to return output of shape `(125, 125, 1)`

Comment: Hi @S.Mohsensh.  Isn't that what this line `x = np.array(new_array).reshape(-1, 125, 125, 1)` does?

Comment: No because you have 4 channels and use `-1` as first shape it creates 4 arrays for a single image, thus getting 4 predictions for just one image. you have to make an array of shape `(1, 125, 125, 1)` for a single image (i.e. `batch_size=1`)